# Multiple categories of item in sitemap.xml

Tags: seo, sitemap

On my site I have items that can be in few or more categories.

Links to one item may look like (for example):

```
example.com/category_id_1/item_id_1
example.com/category_id_67/item_id_1
example.com/category_id_106/item_id_1
```

So I dont understand do I need to set all links for one item in sitemap.xml or just certain one? If only one - which one?

Which way would be more correct according to SEO optimization?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0):

If all the three URLs serves same content it will create some duplicate content issues.

You didn't mention whether you are using a dedicated product URL or not. Better approach to use product URLs will be something like,

yourdomain.com/products/xyx-product